# How to set custom layout into material toolbar?

Tags: android, toolbar

I'm trying to make toolbar like in this app:

play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.pickup.pickrup

But I can't set custom layout into toolbar.

After adding custom layout appears some margins below and above.

Help me please!

Comment: Add some code and maybe screenshots.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this problem specifying instead layout height android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
this - landroid:layout_height="?actionBarSize", which is 56dp.

So margins from top and bottom have dissapeared.

Answer (score 0):

The `Toolbar` is just a `ViewGroup`, so if you have your layout or custom view you can just add it to the `Toolbar` using the `ViewGroup#addView(View view)` method. For example, if you instantiated your view and called it `myView`, you can do: `myToolbar.addView(myView)`